# Toast Notification Arguments Open Web Browser

Tags: microsoft-metro

I need to send my toast notification arguments and open a web browser. Here is my code:

```
private void DoNotification()
    {
        var notifications = serviceClient.GetNotificationsAsync(App.CurrentRestaurantLocation.ID);
        foreach (RestaurantNotification note in notifications.Result)
        {
            IToastNotificationContent toastContent = null;
            IToastText02 templateContent = ToastContentFactory.CreateToastText02();
            templateContent.TextHeading.Text = note.Title;
            templateContent.TextBodyWrap.Text = note.Message;
            toastContent = templateContent;
            // Create a toast, then create a ToastNotifier object to show
            // the toast
            ToastNotification toast = toastContent.CreateNotification();

            toast.Activated += toast_Activated;
            // If you have other applications in your package, you can specify the AppId of
            // the app to create a ToastNotifier for that application
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
        }
    }

    async void toast_Activated(ToastNotification sender, object args)
    {
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    }
```

My activated event happens, however, no web browser opens. That launcher code works without the toast notification.

How do I populate args with a url? My web service returns note.RedirectUrl and I want to feed it in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `Activated` event handler on the `ToastNotification`, use the `OnLaunched` handler in the main Application class (which allows launch context to be easily accessed).

For the handler to be invoked, a [launch argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br230846.aspx) needs to be provided in the toast XML.  Using the code above, you can add the argument to the the `IToastContent` object like so:

```
toastContent.Launch = note.RedirectUrl;
```

Then in the Application's `OnLaunched` method, the app can retrieve the launch argument:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Argument)) {
        var redirectUrl = args.Argument;
    }
}
```

Calling `LaunchUriAsync` should work as expected when used from `OnLaunched`.